# create exe file from windows universal app

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, winjs, win-universal-app

I have created a windows universal app with WinJS in visual studio 2015. Now I can run it from my visual studio. How can i make an exe file of the app so that i can distribute it to my friends? Is it only possible to upload in windows store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're talking about an app for Windows 10!?
There are several ways to get this done.
The  best way is to distribute it via Windows Store. You can hide the app there so that it is only visible to people who have the direct link to the app.
Your friends can download it directly from the store.

Another option is to provide the live IDs of your friends in the store. Then your friends get an email with a direct link.

The option you might actually be looking for which doesn't involve the store at all is to create an app package and to deploy this package to your friends.  (See screenshot)
 For Windows Store Apps you won't create an .exe-File, you only create .appx Packages.

[image]

Choose not to upload to the store in the next dialog. Then click create.
In the output directory you will find the *.appx file (not an *.exe)

You can distribute the appx via sideloading. Simply copy the content of the output folder to your friends's machine and run the ps1 script in Powershell. This will start the installation of the app.

Little hint: This requires your friends PCs to be enabled  for sideloading.
You can set this in the settings dialog. See Screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly the answer i wanted :)

Comment: Each time I try this I get `error APPX0107: The certificate specified is not valid for signing`. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In Current Windows Dev account, you can use Promotional codes to distribute the app to your friends instead of using side load.If the app is company app, I recommend by using sideload method.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan I think this does answer the question, or at least has merit to help someone in the future.